# How to pass state to components rendered by Router

Tags: reactjs, gallery, portfolio

I am making a React portfolio and one of the components will be an image gallery (needless to say I am a newbie to React, I wonder, or I'd not be asking this question). To do so, I will use a package (react-image-gallery), which allows me to customize several items. I already installed, and it works well, but I need to customize it - hide thumbnails and "play" and "fullscreen" buttons.

According to the documentation, it is possible to do so via the state. The issue is that I am failing to do so because the navigation of the App uses a router, and although I tried hard, I could not make the state pass into the component placed on Router. This is the code of the main component (the equivalent to App) which is not working:

```
import "./styles.css";

import {
  HashRouter,
  NavLink,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Development from "./Development";
import Home from "./Home";
import Intro from "./Intro";
import Media from "./Media";
import StudyCase from './StudyCase';
import Stuff from "./Stuff";

class Main extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            showThumbnails: false
        };
    }
  render() {
    return (
            <HashRouter>
                <div>
                    <ul className='top-menu'>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink className='navs hvr-pulse' to='/'>
                                Home
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink className='navs hvr-pulse' to='/dev'>
                                Development
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink className='navs hvr-pulse' to='/media'>
                                Media
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink className='navs' to='/study-case'>
                                Study Case
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <span className='bottom-slider'></span>
                    <div className='content'>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Intro} />
                        <Route path='/dev' component={Development} />
                        <Route path='/media' component={Media} />
                        <Route path='/study-case' render={props => (<StudyCase {...this.state} showThumbnails={this.state.showThumbnails}/>)}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </HashRouter>
        );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Can some of the colleagues point the error I am doing to me? Thanks in advance for the availability.

Comment: Have you tried this:   <Route path='/study-case' render={props => (<StudyCase {...props}  showThumbnails={this.state.showThumbnails}/>)}/>

Comment: Actually you have 2 Routes with the same path '/study-case', you should only have one Route per path

Comment: @HermitCrab, thanks for the heads up. The duplicity was just here, it was made at the time I was copy-pasting the code here. Unfortunately, the code you proposed didn't work (it was one of the things I had tested before...).

Comment: You are missing `/` in `path` of `study-case`. Try this: `<Route path="/study-case" render={(props) => <StudyCase showThumbnails={this.state.showThumbnails} />} />`

Comment: @AjeetShah, thanks as well, but the problem was not there as well (actually, the `/` was in the original code or the page wouldn't render)

Comment: @cgobbet Is there any error? Why does it not render? Everything looks fine. I think there is some issue inside `StudyCase` component.

Comment: Hello@AjeetShah. It was not passing the state because the state does not live on the main project page, but on `<StudyCase />` component. Once inserted there, state worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours looking for the solution, I nailed it, and it was pretty basic, so a newbie could find the answer. It happened that the `<StudyCase/>` component had a component itself,  and the state should live there. I was led to error by the rationale of a gallery package I was working with before, where state had to be manipulated in the same page of the router. Here is the code of the `<StudyCase/>` component, with the working state, if someone may need at some point:

```
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
import React from 'react';

class StudyCase extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            showThumbnails: false,
            showPlayButton: false,
            showFullscreenButton: false,
            showGalleryFullscreenButton: false,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageGallery
                items={images}
                showThumbnails={this.state.showThumbnails}
                showPlayButton={this.state.showPlayButton && this.state.showGalleryPlayButton}
                showFullscreenButton={
                    this.state.showFullscreenButton && this.state.showGalleryFullscreenButton
                }
            />
            // <ImageGallery
            //          items={images}
            //          showThumbnails={this.state.showThumbnails} />;
        );
    }
}

const images = [
    {
        original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/',
        thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/250/150/',
    },
    {
        original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/',
        thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/',
    },
    {
        original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/600/',
        thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/250/150/',
    },
];

export default StudyCase;
```